# What does "go someone late" mean?

Tags: meaning

I came across it in this [article](https://www.bbc.com/sport/boxing/50675638).

> WBA world super-middleweight champion Callum Smith: "If Ruiz wins again I wouldn't be one bit surprised. I do think you'll see a more switched-on Joshua who is more like Lennox Lewis and Wladimir Klitschko. It could be boring but **I'm** **going Joshua late**."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Go with something/someone* can be used to indicate your choice:

> [go with somethig](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+with)
>   2. Fig. to choose something (over something else).
>   *I think I'll go with the yellow one. We decided to go with the oak table rather than the walnut one.*
>   (TFD)

My first thought was that *with* was elided by the speaker. This is fine in casual speech. However, I think you could also simply take *go* to mean choose, or *predict*. One way to see this is that we can use *go* to mean *bet*:

> [go](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/go)  v.tr.
>   4. Informal
>   a. To bet: go $20 on the black horse.

We often say *bet something will happen* (without actually wagering anything) simply to give a prediction, [guess, or opinion](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bet).

In other words, *go (with) Joshua* tells us that the speaker *predicts* Joshua will be the eventual winner. *Late* just tells us when he will win. A more formal sentence would be:

> I predict Joshua will win late in the fight.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the commentator thinks that Joshua is going to win the fight in the later rounds.

Comment: Thank you for contributing. I'm commenting as a reviewer because your answer was flagged as low quality because of its length. It is at risk of being voted down or deleted. Can you add some reasoning for why you think it means that, so that the questioner can learn more easily?